# WARNING: Use strings for Figaro configuration in rails migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-migrations

I am creating new rails migration but it's show me error "WARNING: Use strings for Figaro configuration. 3543009 was converted to "3543009"."

here is my migration

rails g  PaymentInfo Post userid:integer type:string

Comment: please post your Figaro config file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Figaro uses strictly only Strings. One of your configuration values in the application.yml file is a Integer, and this warning announce his class transformation.